# 743: unexpected token at '... in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I saved a file named array.json on my Dropbox folder and i access to it via Dropbox API. All works fine, but when i retrieve JSON content i cannot JSON.parse that string!!

```
session = DropboxSession.new(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
session.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
client = DropboxClient.new(session, ACCESS_TYPE)

json = client.get_file(DIRECTORY + '/array.json')
```

@json = JSON.parse json
Error:

743: unexpected token at '{"Nome" : "Mario Rossi",
"C.F." : "ABCDEFGHILMNOP",
"Booking Assistance" : "MARIO",
"Status of reservation" :  "25/11/2011"}'
JSON string is valid!! if i copy this string and paste it (manually) as parameter in JSON.parse(), json is parsed correctly!! So i think is a encoding problem...but where i wrong?

Comment: Are the single-quotes part of it?

Comment: Please show us all the controller, model and view code for home.  Routes file too please.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, I don't think the routes will be necessary. This is a JSON parsing bug.  Can you post the original JSON you're trying to parse?  It appears that the parser is having difficulty reading it, so maybe you need to do something with it before trying to parse it (though this does sound a little odd).

Comment: My code: 
@json = JSON.parse client.get_file(DIRECTORY + '/data.json')

Comment: Update this question, don't ask a new one on exactly the same topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have abandoned the json parsing backend that is the default in Rails. The default backend is YAML based and imo a useless mess. After several gotchas parsing unicode, and dates in some cases, we discovered that the backend can be replaced via configuration.

You can substitute the parsing backend in an initializer

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.backend = "JSONGem"
```

There are several gems that can be used as the backend, we just use the json gem

```
gem 'json'
```

Comment: i alredy use JSONGem backend. Here's my code

ActiveSupport::JSON.backend

OUTPUT

MultiJson::Engines::JsonGem

Comment: MultiJson is not immune to this problem. Try the json gem and/or json/pure

Comment: Thank you so much for require 'json/pure', so JSON.parse correctly parses response.body of net/http